モーションキャプチャーソフトから出力されたFBXのモーションの反映について
Unityで開発しております。
モーションキャプチャーソフトから出力されたFBXのモーションをランタイムで読み込むために
「TriLib2」を使用しております。
読み込んだモーションデータを表示するための3D人型モデルに反映させるために、取得したファイルパスに
したがって3D人型モデルのファイルパスをリネームしております。
モーションが反映されてアニメーションは行われるのですが、T-Poseの互換性が無いために
見た目はぐちゃぐちゃに表示されてしまっております。
T-Poseの互換を行うためにはどの項目に対して変換処理を行い、AnimationClipを作成すればよいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します
